# Raso/popolo/gento/etno/loĝantaro

Tags: word-difference

I'm pretty sure I got them all sorted out right but I'm having a little trouble figuring out how loĝantaro, etno, and popolo are different.

Raso-race, concerned with your genetics and physical features.

Gento-tribe is probably the closest word. People of different families with a common ancestor usually having their own stories about their origin and have a common ruler.

Etno-ethnicity, your traditions, beliefs, language that identify you with a group of people.

Loĝantaro-population, the whole of people who live in a certain defined area (city, state, country).

Popolo-group of people living together who are different than other groups around them. (I know popolo has other meanings to but I'm concerned with this one)

Where I live there's lots of hispanics and Latinos and I'm white, so we are part of the same population but different groups. But isn't that your ethnicity?

Answer (score 2):

There's a saying, the kind of things you see on t-shirts and pins : ***ĉiuj unu popolo*** - all (the world is) one people. You certainly couldn't say that the whole world is one *etno*, and it wouldn't be very impressive to assert that the word is one *loĝantaro*.

*Loĝantaro* simply refers to the people living in a certain area. *Popolo* has a few meaning. Basically it's the subjects of a single government, or a group of people living in an area distinct from neighboring groups. *Etno* is similar, but the divide seems to run deeper. A clarifying example may be that you can have an *etna lingvo* but not a *popola lingvo.*

Comment: Would a good example be people from different states? like Texas where I live and New York. We're similar enough to be of the same etno and many of us are the same raso, but we're still different. If I visited NYC I'd be able to tell that the people are different there than here.

Comment: A good example of which one? We can talk about the American people as *loĝantaro* if we mean the collection of people who live here. We can say *popolo* if we mean the populace in contrast to government. It's seems a little bit of a stretch to imagine an American and a Canadian talking about *mia popolo kaj via popolo* - but that's not **quite** a crazy notion. I could imagine speaking of the certain Indian groups as a *popolo* and even an *etno*. As for New York, I would hope that someone from TX would notice a difference between Rochester and NYC. There's no clearly defined line, though.

Comment: I think I understand it better now but is this use of popolo that common? It seems like when I see it it means the subjects of the government in contrast to the government itself. I was thinking maybe this definition isn't something to fuss about.

Comment: The definition of "popolo" as "a people", that is, a group usually living in one country and distinct from its neighbors, is indeed very common - especially when used as a plural. He's a more famous example. ***la unuan fojon en la homa historio ni, membroj de la plej malsamaj popoloj staras unu apud alia ne kiel fremduloj,***

Comment: That one makes a lot of sense. :)